# Letting end-users create their own custom queries dynamically with asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq, dynamic-queries

I seriously need some guidance here, so my college teacher gave us this weird assignment, he wants us to create a GUI that displays the tables from the database, allowing the end-user to choose what tables he desires to  query, once he has chosen his table(s) what does he desire to do with it? for instance it could be a select, update or delete statement, after that, we have to let them make use of the WHERE clause so that they can be more specific about their queries, not only that, we also have to give them the chance to make join queries, so they can select more than one tables, and also they have be able to select specific fields  they want to show from their tables.

So I'm not asking you to make my weird homework, but to give me a starting point, some place where I can begin working this out, or maybe some examples you can provide me to give me a better idea on how to start doing this.

By the way this has to be in either asp.net or asp.net MVC, so I really appreciate any guidance you can provide me, keep in mind this is just a homework assignment, so security issues are not a concern here.

Comment: Which DBMS does your assignment assume will be used?

Comment: Simple: display a big text-box and let them type SQL. Just like [this site](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/queries).

Comment: It would be SQL Server any version of it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to present the user with a list of database objects, I would look into leveraging [SQL Management Objects (SMO)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162169.aspx).

From there, you can either [go the easy way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18552835/letting-end-users-create-their-own-custom-queries-dynamically-with-asp-net#comment27292390_18552835) or create a wizard-style interface with steps related to each part of a SQL statement and build up the text behind the scenes.

Once you have a SQL statement to execute, you should review [the ADO.NET documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e80y5yhx.aspx) to find out how to execute it.

Comment: Thank you so much M.Babcock, I think you did understand my question based on your answer, I managed to made some simple queries dynamically using SMO objects to present the list of tables available, and from that I let the user choose the field they want to query and add a little conditions by implementing a where clause, it's not perfect but this assignment was a bit wacky, anyway if you're interested in seeing my implementation let me know and I can send you my code so you can see how can I make it better.

Thank you so much M.Babcock and I hope I can hear from you more often. thanks.